# PHPExcel unable to create folder /tmp/xxxxxxxx

Tags: phpexcel, redhat

I have a strange behaviour and I need some ideas.

I have a Redhat7 server with standard apache and php7 installation.
The application running on this server uses PHPExcel to export data from a database to an excel file.
Because the appliction is very old and not from me, I dont want to change from PHPExcel to PHPWorksheet if there is any other option.
The server is also not installed by me, but I have sudo access.

What happens:

It looks like every night the server does some changes to the httpd service because every morning when I try to use the application I got an error that PHPExcel cannot create folder /tmp/xxxxxx. All I have to do is restart the httpd service as sudo and the applcation works fine until the next day.

I know this is not much information so if you need something more please ask.

I also know its hard to help here but perhaps someone has a similar problem in the past?

Thanks

Claus

Answer (score 0):

After all I have solution which is not my favorite but it works.

I have changed the

sys_temp_dir

upload_temp_dir

in the php.ini to a different self created folder. It looks like the /tmp folder (which is default) is changed every night from any other application running on the server in that way, that PHP has no longer write access to it. 
I am not very sattisfied not knowing exactly whats going wrong with the /tmp folder but because I am not the admin of the server I think I must be ok with it.